# Managed to break my venv; is it possible to fix?

Tags: python, macos

I managed to break one of my virtual environments. I think I did it by installing `pycrypto` with `pip` and uninstalling it with `easy_install`.

This is what I get when I run `python` in the venv.

```
filip@dratmac:~/PycharmProjects/Project-Marketplace2/backend/odb/helper_objects$ python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 62, in <module>
    import os
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 49, in <module>
    import posixpath as path
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 17, in <module>
    import warnings
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/warnings.py", line 8, in <module>
    import types
  File "types.py", line 1, in <module>
    import json
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 108, in <module>
    from .decoder import JSONDecoder
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 3, in <module>
    import re
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 280, in <module>
    import copy_reg
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 7, in <module>
    from types import ClassType as _ClassType
ImportError: cannot import name ClassType
filip@dratmac:~/PycharmProjects/Project-Marketplace2/backend/odb/helper_objects$
```

And outside the venv everything works as expected:

```
Last login: Tue Apr  7 22:30:08 on ttys005
filip@dratmac:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not name your file `types.py` as there is a standard library module with the same name (`import types`).

As such, Python tries to import it as part of some standard library code but it now actually imports your local `types.py` file, not the module it expects.

So the problem should be fixed when you rename `types.py` to something else.